# What is the best way to give name to different cases in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I was wondering if someone can tell me what is the best way to give name to different states in Verilog? For example instead of the following case

```
case (a)
  1'b0 : statement1;
  1'b1 : statement2;
  1'bx : statement3;
  1'bz : statement4;
endcase
```

It is much better to have a piece of code with this format

```
case (a)
  Load : statement1;
  Store : statement2;
  Check : statement3;
  Reset : statement4;
endcase
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `enum` of `logic` type can help you out. For example, the state variables like IDLE,BUSY etc. of state machine can only have the all the states defined and can be displayed using the state name, that is `enum`s.

**Enums** can be defined as follows:

```
enum logic {Load,Store,Check,Reset} a;
```

You can **explicitly** assign values to enum as follows:

```
enum logic {Load='0,Store='1,Check='x,Reset='z} a;
```

Also, you have **built-in methods** like `first`, `last`, `name` etc. to perform operations on `enum`s.

Here is an exact code what I am trying to explain:

```
module top();
  enum logic {Load='0,Store='1,Check='x,Reset='z} a;
  initial
    begin
      case (a)
        Load : $display("1");
        Store :  $display("2");
        Check :  $display("3");
        Reset :  $display("4");
      endcase
    end 
endmodule
```

For more information, refer to [Enumerations](http://www.testbench.in/SV_06_ENUMARATIONS.html) link.

Answer (score 2):

If not wanting to use enums then localparams are also a good way of using mnemonics for your states.

```
localparam LOAD  = 1'b0;
localparam STORE = 1'b1;
localparam CHECK = 1'bx;
localparam RESET = 1'bz;

always @* begin
  case (a)
    LOAD : statement1;
    STORE : statement2;
    CHECK : statement3;
    RESET : statement4;
  endcase
end
```

Most languages use upper case to denote constants, it is also good practice to do this in Verilog with localparams and parameters.